# Numerical precision and logarithms

Tags: r, floating-point, logarithm

I'm having a problem (at least I think I have a problem) with the following calculation:

```
ppm <- 20
mDa <- 2
x <- c( 100, 100.002 )

base  <- 1 + ((x * ppm * 1E-6) + (mDa * 1E-3))/x
base
# [1] 1.00004 1.00004
base - 1.00004
# [1]  0.00000e+00 -3.99992e-10

logb( x[2], base[2] ) - logb( x[1], base[1] )
# [1] 1.651291
```

However, I would have expected that the result is *approximately* `0.5`, since I expected the base to be in both cases to be *approximately* `1.00004`:

```
logb( x[2], 1.00004 ) - logb( x[1], 1.00004 )
# [1] 0.500005
```

Although I have no proof at hand, I doubt that the result of `logb( x[2], 1.00004 ) - logb( x[1], 1.00004 )` is mathematically correct and I assume that I hit a numerical precision issue. Any ideas how to avoid this problem are highly appreciated.

*Edit*

### What I'm actually trying to do

I need to rescale positive numbers `(a, b) -> (a',b')` with `b > a`, such that the difference of two numbers on the new scale `d'( a', b' ) = b' - a'` is larger 1 iff the difference on the original scale `d(a, b) = b -[ a + ( a * ppm * 1E-6) + (mDa * 1E-3)]` is larger zero. I know that there might be a problem, because `d(a, b) ≠ d(b, a)`. Typical ranges for the values are `a,b ∈ [50, 1500]`, `mDa ∈ [0, 10]` and `ppm ∈ [1, 50]`.

Comment: Since `x` is 2-dimensional, so is `(x * ppm * 1E-6) + (mDa * 1E-3)`. What do you mean the difference between `a` and `b` is larger than this value?

Comment: @josilber good question :-/ I edited the last paragraph to (hopfully) clarify things.

Comment: Well, looks like you could do all the rescaling directly without resorting to logarithms or extended precision (`mpfr` or `gmp`). How many digits of precision in `b-a-tiny_number >0` do you really need?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the smallest value `tiny_number` can have with my parameters (`mDa = 0, ppm = 1, a = 50`) would be `5E-5`.

Comment: So you are looking for a single function to convert `a -> a'` and `b -> b'`?

Comment: @James since `a` and `b` are on the same scale I would expect that a single function should do be sufficient

Comment: @Beasterfield Well, doing some basic algebra, I expect you would need something like this `log(x[2]) - log(x[1]*(1+ppm*1e-6)+mDa*1e-3)`, which you can't make into a single function for a and b without knowing which is the largest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're taking logarithms of large numbers with a base very close to 1, small differences in that base can lead to noticeable differences in the final value. Your bases differ by 0.0000000004, but that can make a difference with a base very close to 1:

```
logb(100, 1.0000399996)
# 115132.7
logb(100, 1.00004)
# 115131.6
logb(100, 1.0000400004)
# 115130.4
```

Comment: Take a look at `curve(logb(100,x),0,2)` to see what the issue is: a singularity at `base=1` leads to hyperbolic growth.

Comment: That's true but doesn't really answer the OP's question -- which I interpreted as "how do I maintain sufficient precision when calculating oddball logarithms on a computer?"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm saying here that he isn't experiencing numerical precision issues -- the reason he got 1.65 instead of 0.5 is because of the (small) difference in the base.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- I thought he was wondering why different ways of calculating the base led to different answers :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and josilber many thanks for pointing this out, in this case I must have conceptual mistake in my formula. Any ideas how I reac my actual goal? Please see my Edit for this.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Rmpfr` :

```
Rgames> rfoo<-mpfr(100,100)
Rgames> log100<-log(rfoo)
Rgames> log100
1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
[1] 4.6051701859880913680359829093676
Rgames> logbase<-log(mpfr(1.0004,100))
Rgames> log100/logbase
1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
[1] 11515.227896589510924644721707849
Rgames> logbase<-log(mpfr(1.00004,100))
Rgames> log100/logbase
1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
[1] 115131.55721932987847380223102368
```

Thus showing that josilber's answer is spot-on.

Comment: Did not know about this package, I was actually looking for something like this. Great.

Answer (score 0):

@josiber is right, `log(1.00004)` is approximately `0.00004` so you divide by a tiny number and get huge results... So the difference you observe is relatively small.

If you seek better accuracy without extended precision library, you could also try using `log1p(x)` which compute `log(1+x)`

```
baseM1  <- ((x * ppm * 1E-6) + (mDa * 1E-3))/x
```

then

```
log( x[2] )/log1p( baseM1[2] ) - log( x[1] )/log1p( baseM1[1] )
```

Comment: Did you try it? It doesn't make any difference

Comment: @James you are right, no difference because the diff between bases is about 10^-10. log1p would be interesting with diff approaches 10^-15